# Delegate is not invoked from DispatchQueue.global() thread

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a scenario where I need to load data from a JSON object, I've created an helper class that does that and it looks like this

```swift
protocol JSONDumpHelperDelegate {
    func helper(_: JSONDumpHelper, didFinishFetching: [Link])
    func helper(_: JSONDumpHelper, completionProcess: Double)
}

struct JSONDumpHelper {
    static let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: "com.mattrighetti.Ulry", category: .pointsOfInterest)
    var delegate: JSONDumpHelperDelegate?
    
    func loadFromFile(
        with filemanager: FileManager = .default,
        from url: URL,
        decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
        context: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.shared.managedContext,
        dataFetcher: DataFetcher = DataFetcher()
    ) {
        os_signpost(.begin, log: JSONDumpHelper.pointsOfInterest, name: "loadFromFile")
        
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let dump = try! decoder.decode(Dump.self, from: data)
        
        var tagsHash: [UUID:Tag] = [:]
        if let tagsCodable = dump.tags {
            for tagCodable in tagsCodable {
                let tag = Tag(context: context)
                tag.id = tagCodable.id
                tag.name = tagCodable.name
                tag.colorHex = tagCodable.colorHex
                
                tagsHash[tag.id] = tag
            }
        }
        
        var groupHash: [UUID:Group] = [:]
        if let groupsCodable = dump.groups {
            for groupCodable in groupsCodable {
                let group = Group(context: context)
                group.id = groupCodable.id
                group.name = groupCodable.name
                group.colorHex = groupCodable.colorHex
                group.iconName = groupCodable.iconName
                
                groupHash[group.id] = group
            }
        }
        
        var links: [Link] = []
        if let linksCodable = dump.links {
            let total = linksCodable.count
            var completed = 0.0
            
            delegate?.helper(self, completionProcess: 0.0)
            
            for linkCodable in linksCodable {
                let link = Link(context: context)
                link.id = linkCodable.id
                link.url = linkCodable.url
                link.createdAt = linkCodable.createdAt
                link.updatedAt = linkCodable.updatedAt
                link.colorHex = linkCodable.colorHex
                link.note = linkCodable.note
                link.starred = linkCodable.starred
                link.unread = linkCodable.unread
                
                if let uuidGroup = linkCodable.group?.id {
                    link.group = groupHash[uuidGroup]
                }
                
                if let tags = linkCodable.tags {
                    link.tags = Set<Tag>()
                    for tagUUID in tags.map({ $0.id }) {
                        link.tags?.insert(tagsHash[tagUUID]!)
                    }
                }
                
                links.append(link)
                
                completed += 1
                delegate?.helper(self, completionProcess: completed / Double(total))
            }
        }
        
        os_signpost(.end, log: JSONDumpHelper.pointsOfInterest, name: "loadFromFile")
    }
}
```

This could potentially be a very long running task, just imagine an array with 1k records that also need to fetch data from the internet (not shown in implementation, error still exist with posted code) and you can easily end up with 10s in execution time.

What I'm trying to achieve is to show the user an alert that will show him the progress of the import process, by updating the values with the delegate protocols below.

```swift
extension BackupViewController: JSONDumpHelperDelegate {
    func helper(_: JSONDumpHelper, didFinishFetching: [Link]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.completionViewController.remove()
        }
    }
    
    func helper(_: JSONDumpHelper, completionProcess: Double) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.completionViewController.descriptionLabel.text = "Completed \(Int(completionProcess * 100))%"
        }
    }
}
```

The import method is fired from a `UITableView`, immediately after the user choses a file from a `DocumentPickerViewController`

```swift
extension BackupViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        self.initImport(for: urls)
    }
}
```

```swift
private func initImport(for urls: [URL]) {
    if let url = urls.first {
        completionViewController.add(self, frame: self.view.bounds)
        completionViewController.descriptionLabel.text = "Fetching"
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            self.dumpHelper.loadFromFile(from: url)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when the user initiates the import process, the UI is not updated until the process itself is finished.

If I place breakpoints both at the protocol implementations and at the `delegate` calls in the helper class I can see that the delegate is not called immediately but they all get fired when the process ended (but the alert controller does not update its values).

Just to place some more info I'm going to replicate an import of N elements from JSON:

1. User clicks import process
2. `initImport` is executed (nothing is shown on UI even if I add the custom vc to view)
3. `JSONDumpHelper.loadFromFile` is executed entirely, calling `delegate` N times, nothing called in the `delegate` implementation
4. `loadFromFile` finishes execution
5. `delegate` implementation of `helper(_:, completionProcess)` is executed N times, UI always shows "Completed 0%"
6. `delegate` implementation of `helper(_:, didFinishFetching)` is executed, controller is removed from view

Can anybody point out what is wrong with this implementation? It seems like the `loadFromFile` function is not working in a separate Queue and UI is stuck and can't update as expected.

Comment: Are you sure the value of completionProcess is not always 0?

Comment: Yes @AndreyChernukha, from the breakpoint inspector I can see that it changes from 0, 0.123, 0.32, 0.57 and so on

Comment: What if you set self.completionViewController.descriptionLabel.text = "Whatever"? Does it update? What if you do this from a different function unrelated to the workflow you've described?

Comment: I've tried to display a random value every time the delegate is called and nothing happens, only the very last call changes the value but the N-1 calls before that do not

Comment: If you add a print of `completionProcess` in the delegate method, before the `DispatchQueue` does it print the correct value, an "n" times? Could it be that your parsing is too "quick"?

Comment: @Larme yes it does! The print statement gets executed correctly and does print the correct value every time the delegate is called if placed outside the `DispatchQueue.main` section, interesting catch. So you suspect that the UI update is called too frequently in a small fraction of time?

Comment: First, if you have a ten second process and you're not seeing the periodic updates getting called, that means that the main thread is blocked. Second, I don't know how many URLs are in `urls`, but you've got a thread explosion (which can, in certain cases, lead to blocking). Third, re “UI update is called too frequently”, if that is really happening, one might consider a dispatch source to allow the main thread to process the events at whatever rate it can, without any backlogging. IMHO, we need a MCVE to help diagnose which is the problem here. It's hard to diagnose if we can't reproduce.

Comment: Is the urls that you are passing *network* urls?  If so, you should not use `Data(contentsOf:)`. That initialiser should only be used for local file urls. If `loadFromFile` Doesn't access the network it is going to be CPU bound and it will not free the main thread to allow the UI updates to be dispatched. Even though you have dispatched the load onto another queue it is almost certainly going to be using the main thread. Finally, `.userInitiated` is probably a better QoS then `.userInteractive` for this work

Comment: @Paulw11 it's a single url passed from the `DocumentPickerVC` that takes in a json file, so no network call in that. How can you show the user that the process is ongoing if I can't even pop up an alter message by calling a method?

Comment: Well, I would start with `.userInitiated` instead of `.userInteractive`, but how long does it take to process the local JSON file?  I would have thought a fraction of a second unless it is millions of records.  I think you would see very different behaviour if you had a primarily IO bound task that is fetching lots of data from the network vs a CPU bound task as you have here.  iOS isn't pre-emptive; an async dispatch will happen *at some time in the future*.  You could try inserting a `sleep` after your async dispatch to relinquish the CPU

Comment: Also, I would probably re-think the strategy of calling the progress delegate method for every record; If you have few records then you are going to complete processing them all before the user evens sees the progress bar move and if you have many records then the change in completion % from one record to the next is going to be imperceptible most of the time.  I would calculate 1% of your record count and only call the delegate when you have processed 1 more % (ie when `completed % onePercent == 0`)

Comment: @Paulw11 that is the case I'm facing now, I have tested with a bunch of records but they are parsed in like 4ms. I also tried every qos but `background` and `default`, but UI is not updated even with that. Also, I don't understand why the very first alert controller is not added in the view hierarchy at all even if the function is not yet fired and the main thread should be free to act.

Comment: There just isn't time for a layout pass to execute.  Try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` after you add the view to force a layout pass.  I just think you are trying to test behaviour that is needed with long running, IO bound tasks using a short running, CPU bound task and you aren't going to get the results you expect because of that.

Comment: @Paulw11 great then, I think that could be a good answer for this as it seems perfectly reasonable